# Solve the system $1=c_1+c_2$, $3 = (1+i)c_1 + (1-i)c_2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have from the first equation that $c_1 = 1-c_2$

So we can just substitute that into the second equation and solve for $c_2$, right? I do so below: $$3 = (1+i)c_1 + (1-i)c_2 = (1+i)(1-c_2) + (1-i)c_2$$

$$3=1-c_2+i-ic_2 + c_2 -ic_2 =1+i-2ic_2  $$

$$\implies c_2= \frac{3-1-i}{-2i} = \frac{2-i}{-2i} =\color{red}{\frac1{-i}}+\frac12$$

But apparently $c_2=1/2 -i$. Which step in my solution was wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Red colored is $i$ and not $-i$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 3= \underbrace{(c_1+c_2)}_1+i(c_1-c_2)\implies c_1-c_2 = -2i$$

So $$c_1 = {1-2i\over 2}\;\;\;\wedge\;\;\;c_2 ={1+2i\over 2}$$